# How to work around 403 Forbidden so I can view AMP version of page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-status-code-403

https://amp.theguardian.com/education/2016/mar/05/harvard-law-school-drops-official-shield-over-slavery-links allows you to view the [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) version of the site on desktop.

But the NYT has blocked AMP pages on desktop (it 403's): http://mobile.nytimes.com/2016/03/05/books/pat-conroy-who-wove-his-family-strife-into-novels-of-carolina-dies-at-70.amp.html

I've tried spoofing the agent in DevTools and even throttling my connection speed, but they're still able to detect I'm on desktop.

Is there anything else I can do? I want to make a Chrome Extension that views the AMP version of all sites that have it available.

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you're expecting. You're asking to circumvent access controls on a third-party website, which isn't very.. ethical.

Comment: Preventing me from viewing a site simply because I'm on desktop because they want to feed me more ads and JS spam isn't particularly ethical either. Oh well.

Comment: @corysimmons that's not StackOverflow's problem : )